# I am trying to make a yes or no question that if you click no it askes the question again

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, while-loop

I am new to python and i want to make something that asks your either: Yes or No. If the user says yes it does something and if they say no it asks the question again until they say yes. How do i do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

A simple example is:

```py
answer = input('Your question. Please answer yes or no.')

while answer != 'yes':
    answer = input('Your question. Please answer yes/no.')

# executes only once answer == 'yes'
something()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    answer = input('Question: ')
    if answer == 'Yes':
        # do something
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple while loop with some assertions...

```
answer = input('Do you agree? y/n')
assert answer in ['y', 'n'], 'Please answer only with a "y" or a "n"'
answer = input('Do you agree? y/n')
while answer == 'n':
    answer = input('Do you agree? y/n')
    assert answer in ['y', 'n'], 'Please answer only with a "y" or a "n"'
# If we're here the user has finally answered "y"
do_something()
```